# Should marketing side and app side of a web app be one or two different SPA apps?

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I'm setting up an AngularJs site.  One part is the marketing side of things (FAQ, Home page, how it works, etc) and the other part is the actual web app (authenticated).  The web app is currently a SPA.  Should the marketing part of it be part of the same SPA or a separate SPA?

Pulse.me has a very nice SPA type application.

https://www.pulse.me/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this same issue in my app.  I ended up going for two separate SPA.  My main reasoning was that I didn't want to expose JavaScript to unauthenticated users because you would be able to see calls being made to the back-end.  Yes the back-end would reject them, but why even allow the random web crawler or hacker to see what they are.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, two seperate SPA apps. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Hi, it's been a while since you answered but I am in a similar situation. I have the added complication that my client wants to the user to be able to login / sign up / perform a search from the marketing page. The search will offer a public mode and authenticated mode. 
Did you have to handle something similar and if so, how? Thanks